# Enum-Based State Machine Modeling

Tags: design-patterns

In my state machine, I have a state that has *sub-states*. Whenever the-sub states's are done, I would like to go back to the state prior to those sub-states.

In order to achieve this I *store* the *Previous State* inside those sub-states:

```
enum AppState {
 case StateA
 case StateB
 indirect case StateC-1(previousState: AppState)
 indirect case StateC-2(previousState: AppState)
 indirect case StateC-3(previousState: AppState)
}
```

This is pretty cumbersome and feels incorrect. Can anyone suggest a better design for this?

Comment: Use stack data structure.

Comment: Thanks. I need some more information though

Comment: Try to google “stack based state machine” for more info.

Comment: Haven't found anything clear yet

Comment: Have you read about general stack data structure and its usage?

Comment: You've asked about a better design, not best practice. Furthermore, there will be no code, implementing a best practice, you'll have to write it by yourself according some theoretical explanation.

Comment: Maybe the wording of the question isn't accurate enough, but I _am_ looking for code that demonstrates this, or at least pseudo code (or structure). I can change it so that it contains more code and makes it more specific. (I just realized problem could help other languages as well)